# How to change font size in qooxdoo table rows?

Tags: javascript, fonts, font-size, qooxdoo

How to change font size of data in qooxdoo table `qx.ui.table.Table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method for adjusting the font of the table is in the Row Renderer (typically `qx.ui.table.rowrenderer.Default`) and is called `_renderFont`. It's protected, but probably shouldn't be.

The default font that's used is the one called `default` in the current theme. You can specify a different font for the Row Renderer to use, by selecting a different font from your theme:

```
table
  .getDataRowRenderer()
  ._renderFont(qx.theme.manager.Font.getInstance().resolve("myTableFont"));
```

or if you don't want to modify the theme for it, explicitly, such as:

```
table
  .getDataRowRenderer()
  ._renderFont(qx.bom.Font.fromString("20px Arial"));
```

Alternatives:

You could `patch` qx.ui.table.cellrenderer.Abstract, but that's a lot more destructive than calling a protected method. As I said, that `_renderFont` method really should be public.
In fact, I would definitely entertain a pull request that added a public method in `qx.ui.table.rowrenderer.Default` called something like `setFont`, that called `_renderFont`, or moved the logic from `_renderFont` into `setFont` and then defined `_renderFont` as an alias for `setFont`. (I wouldn't remove `_renderFont` entirely as it has possibly been overridden by peoples' row renderers that extend `qx.ui.table.rowrenderer.Default`.

Another alternative, is to extend `qx.ui.table.rowrenderer.Default` and then call `table.setDataRowRenderer` passing an instance of your extended row renderer.

Comment: Thank a lot, but as you've said it's protected and also looks like hidden solution (not obvious) looking through public API. Btw what about redefining qx.ui.table.cellrenderer.Abstract ? If it is right direction I will dive into it and write my answer here.

Comment: I've edited the answer, adding a bit more explanation and some alternatives to solve the problem.